# 6.2 GB usable ram out of 8 GB RAM

Tags: laptop, ram

When I bought a new laptop it had 4 GB RAM. Then after 1 month I added 4 GB RAM in the second slot. And it shows 7.88 GB RAM usable. After some time it showed 6.4 GB RAM usable and 1.4 GB hardware reserved. So I formatted and installed Linux. Now in Linux it shows only 6.2 GB RAM usable. I have talked to Dell customer care. And read many forum. I searched Google a lot, but nothing helped me.

Comment: What did you try already? Before you formatted, what OS were you using? You can [edit] to add.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your looking at the right stats. Perhaps you are looking at the *available* memory and not the **total** memory. Run this command in the terminal:

```
free -m
```

and see what it says.

Another possibility is your new ram is just bad, and may need to be replaced.

Comment: i have checked the ram in another laptop always working fine.  free -m  total memory  6375

Comment: Definitely sounds like bad RAM then. Might wanna see if you can return it...

Comment: I put another ram. And this happens again exactly same